# How to select only distinct value from row by creating a distinct key in sql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

[image: sample output]I am creating a distinct key by concatenating two different columns of a table. Now the key which I have created can be repeated, for example column A is roll number of student and column B is the optional subject in which he is enrolled. Now a student can be enrolled in multiple subjects as well as single optional subject, I want only those students roll number who are enrolled in only single optional subjects.

Using this query I am getting a 3rd column with concatenated value but I want only those students who are enrolled in single subject, I am not sure how to proceed in this case, please help.

```
SELECT roll_number, optional_subject,
       CONCAT(roll_number, optional_subject) as key
  FROM
       student
 WHERE time BETWEEN '2023-03-12' AND '2023-03-13'
 GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2,3 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` Guessing a bit here. If you add sample data and desired results it would help a lot.

Comment: Do you mean students who aren't enrolled in any regular subjects, only an optional subject? Use `WHERE subject IS NULL` to filter out the rows with normal subjects.

Comment: I want only those students who are enrolled only in one optional subjects regardless of regular subject.

Comment: My desired output is only the student who is enrolled in history(row5), please look added image for reference.

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `select roll_number from mytable group by 1 having count(*) = 1`?

Comment: I am not clear what the distinction between regular and optional subject is or why only row 5 is required in the output since row 1 also has only 1 subject, Compound key also looks pointless